# dovecot mailbox settings auto-create vs auto-subscribe

Tags: postfix, dovecot, mailbox

I read this [document](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/namespace/#core_setting-namespace/mailbox/auto), but still do not understand difference between following:

```
mailbox Junk {
    auto = create # autocreate Junk, but don't autosubscribe
    special_use = \Junk
}

mailbox Junk {
    auto = subscribe # autocreate and autosubscribe the Junk mailbox
    special_use = \Junk
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The box's with `auto=subscribe` ( will be created auto once you set your IMAP account on your email client for the first-time). while the `auto = create`, you will need to subscribe manually to it after you setup your IMAP on your client.

Comment: This is actually incorrect, "auto = subscribe" will create and subscribe, while "auto = create" will create but not subscribe.

Comment: @TriadicTech your answer is correct